# Test projects building to common output directory?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, csproj

I have set the build output path of all projects to common debug and release directories:

```
<OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)BuildOutput\Release</OutputPath>
```

Should the test projects also output to this directory or should they build to their own release (bin) directories?

I am using VS 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test projects should build to their own Release \ Debug directory.  This is because they are separate project; they are executed separately (ie with a Test Runner) and are deployed separately.  If you have a project called Mvc and a project called Mvc.Test, you're probably not going to want to deploy Mvc.Test to your web server.